# Qt with GDIplus can't read the exif value of a jpeg image (id, type, length working)

Tags: c++, qt, gdi+

i want to read the exif data of jpeg images with a windows application in qt.
I uses this function: [Image.GetAllPropertyItems class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp)

i could load all property items and display it in a textBrowser for testing:

```
PropertyItem* pAllItems = (PropertyItem*)malloc(totalBufferSize);
image->GetAllPropertyItems(totalBufferSize, numProperties, pAllItems);
... loop ...
ui->textBrowser->append(QString::number(pAllItems[xxx].id));    
ui->textBrowser->append(QString::number(pAllItems[xxx].type));
ui->textBrowser->append(QString::number(pAllItems[xxx].length));
```

So i could see the id, type and length of my exif data and thats working great.

But i can't read the value of PropertyItem. The datatype is different and could be checked with the type.
I want to read the time of the exif data (id == 0x9003), the type is 2 ([have a look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.type(v=vs.110).aspx)) and the length is 20.

**Microsoft writes:**

> Specifies that Value is a null-terminated ASCII string. If you set the type data member to ASCII type, you should set the Len property to the length of the string including the null terminator. For example, the string "Hello" would have a length of 6.

I tried so many ways like this:

```
QByteArray propItem = pAllItems[xxx].value;
```

but i dont know what i do wrong. Qt didnt compile it:

> C2240: "Initalisation": 'void *' cannot convert to 'QByteArray'

I think i know what the compiler means, but i didnt have any idea to solve it. I would be happy if somebody could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Qt is C++, it's not a programming language nor a dialect. It was the Visual Studio C++ compiler that didn't compiler.

Comment: `malloc` in a C++ program!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the type is a string, you should reinterpret the `value` to mean a pointer to a null-terminated ASCII string, precisely as the documentation you cited states:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < numProperties; ++i) {
  auto const & property = pAllItems[i];
  ui->textBrowser->append(QString::number(property.id));    
  ui->textBrowser->append(QString::number(property.type));
  ui->textBrowser->append(QString::number(property.length));
  auto valueStr{QStringLiteral("value of an unhandled type")};
  switch (property.type) {
  case PropertyTagTypeASCII: 
    valueStr = QString::fromLatin1(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(property.value),
                                   property.length);
    break;
  case PropertyTagTypeByte:
    valueStr = QString::number(*reinterpret_cast<qint8*>(property.value));
    break;
  // etc.
  default:
    break;
  }
  ui->textBrowser->append(valueStr);
}
```